# Invalid Syntax (:) Python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

```
import random
x=random.randint(1, 99)
guess = int(raw_input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: ")
if guess < x:
   print
   print("Höher!")
   int(raw_input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: "))
if guess > x:
   print
   print("Tiefer!")
   int(Raw_input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: ")
else:
     print("Richtig!)
     break
```

So, I am new to programming and I fell over a (for me a bit frustrating) mistake I can't figure. First Python tells me, the "else" is incorrect. After some search, I found out, what the problem was. I then had spaces before the "ifs" and the "else", which was the next problem. Now I'm stuck with the third syntax error, to which I don't find an answer. After hitting F5, it gives me an "invalid syntax" issue.
Plesae end my seeking for help :)

Comment: raw_input() - 3.6 - is that a thing?

Comment: If that does not give you a`NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`  - you are on python 2.x not 3.x .. fix your taggin please or use `input(...)` - same for `print` vs `print()` as Zev observed

Comment: same with those blank `print` statements

Comment: [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  - and if you post something here, copy & paste the full stacktrace and exact error message - makes it far easier to spot whats wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing parenthesis of the `int` call:

```
guess = int(raw_input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: "))
# Here -----------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: python 3.6 raw_input()?

Answer (score 0):

I have found five mistakes in your code:

1. You are missing a closing parentheses after `guess = int(raw_input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: ")`.
2. You are missing another closing parentheses after `int(Raw_input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: ")`.
3. You are missing a "closing" double quote after `"print("Richtig!`.
4. `break` is used for breaking out of/stopping a loop (`for`, `while`).
5. `raw_input()` isn't a thing in Python 3.x. Use `input()` instead.

Also you have two `print`s, which don't do anything.

Error-free code:

```
import random
x=random.randint(1, 99)
guess = int(input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: "))
if guess < x:
    print("Höher!")
    int(input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: "))
if guess > x:
    print("Tiefer!")
    int(input("Rate eine Zahl von 1 bis 99: "))
else:
    print("Richtig!")
```